# Tkinter - Switch out a Canvas that's in a grid

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'd like to be able to switch out a canvas item that's in a frame - the first time I call this event, it appears to work, but then ceases to respond to events.

```
def switchCanvas(event):
    global state
    global myCanvas
    if (state == 0):
        print("white background")    
        myCanvas = Canvas(rootFrame, bg="white",scrollregion=(0, 0, 10000, 10000))
    if (state == 1):
        print("black background")
    myCanvas = Canvas(rootFrame, bg="black",scrollregion=(0, 0, 10000, 10000))
    state = 1^state
    myCanvas.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=(N, W, E, S))
```

Without the last .grid command, the Python window responds to the events but doesn't update. Does anyone have an idea of why the events aren't being registered? I'm using Python3.

Comment: Your code shows creating a second canvas, but that's not the same as "switching out", because you'll end up with two canvas widgets. "switching out" implies you remove one and replace it with another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You posted less than a minimal example, without the context to confidently answer, but I will try.  First, here is an (untested) improved version of of your func, with the same faults.

```
def switchCanvas(event):
    global myCanvas
    bgcolors = ('white', 'black')
    print(bgcolors[state], "background")
    myCanvas = Canvas(rootFrame, bg=bgcolors[state], scrollregion=(0, 0, 10000, 10000))
    state = 1^state
    myCanvas.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=(N, W, E, S))
```

In your unposted code, you first bound a Canvas widget to the name 'myCanvas'.  Then you bound it to grid cell (0,0).  When the event is first triggered, you rebind 'myCanvas' to an invisible second canvas.  The first is still bound to the cell and is what you see.  If you stop there, you interpret seeing the first canvas as 'the event was not registered', even though is was, because the effect is invisible.  When you rebind the second canvas to the cell, I believe there will be no references to the first canvas and it will be garbage collected.  Why this disables event handling, if it indeed does, I cannot tell without seeing the event binding code.

However, I believe your problem will go away if, instead of creating a new canvas, you just clear myCanvas and switch its background color.

```
def switchCanvas(event):
    bgcolors = ('white', 'black')
    print(bgcolors[state], "background")  
    myCanvas.delete(*myCanvas.find_all())
    myCanvas['bg'] = bgcolors[state]
    state = 1^state
```

Comment: I ran into this debacle because I'm trying to interface with pop-up tkinter windows, but you're right - this serves my purposes admirably. I was in process of creating a more complete example, but it takes me a while (very new to tkinter/not a python expert) - but you crushed it before I was done. 

The part about garbage collection was excellent - I'll have to look into that with my handling of multiple frames. Thanks again!

Comment: Widgets are not garbage-collected, they remain in memory until they are destroyed.

Comment: I have not tried it yet, but `myCanvas.delete('all')` is supposed to clear also.